# Twitter Bootstrap and Modernizr html lang

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modernizr

I have the following at the top of my Twitter bootstrap page, and I am using modernizr. However I need to set the html lang="en"> in order to pass accessibility testing. Where would I put this as Modernizr automatically creates the html tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]>        <html class="no-js ie lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>        <html class="no-js ie lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>        <html class="no-js ie lt-ie10"> <!<![endif]-->
<head>
```

Comment: If I add <html class="no-js" lang="en"> to the end will this still work?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `lang="en"` to HTML tag.

Modernizr **does not** create HTML tag, it only add css classes to it!